# I'd like this preg_match working with my filter_validate_int

Tags: php, validation

I've spend many hours to get this form in this php code to work and i'm asking you now Stackoverflow.

I have this code that i tried to insert a phone input form and i havn't succeeded to make it validate correctly with a exactly length of 8 digits phone number. (ex. 12345678 )

HTML

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <legend>Sign up here.</legend>
    <label>Name  <input type="text" name="na" /></label><br>
    <label>Email <input type="text" name="em" /></label><br>
    <label>Phone <input type="number" name="ph" pattern=".{0}|.{8}" /></label><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" /></form>
```

PHP

```
$nam = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'na', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
or die('Please insert a name.');

$ema = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'em', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
or die('The email you typed is not valid.');

$pho = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ph', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)
or die('Phone number was incorrect. It must contain 8 numbers.');

if(preg_match('/[0-9] {8}/', $pho));





        echo 'Hello ' . $nam . ' we registered your mail as ' . $ema . ' and your phone number as ' . $pho . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;



    $sql = 'INSERT INTO signup (name, email, phone) VALUES (?,?,?)';
    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $nam, $ema, $pho);
    $stmt->execute();

    $link->close();

?>
```

When i insert and submit my form, it doesn't register the preg_match, and inserts the 0 - 7 length digits anyway.

The code worked before i added the phone part, and did not insert name and/or email if it wasn't valid.

Answer (score 2):

I think the extra white space in the regex causes that behavior.

Maybe this will work:

```
if(preg_match('/[0-9]{8}/', $pho)) {
    echo 'Hello ' . $nam . ' we registered your mail as ' . $ema . ' and your phone number as ' . $pho . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
};
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php